# Importing Android and iOS Libraries into a Flutter Project

Tags: android, mobile, libraries, flutter

I am currently deciding to use flutter in a production app.  I am very new to the platform.  I am working my way through some areas that would be pain points for the project to see if flutter will save us time in this project.  I am having some issues with some of these points.

I cannot seem to find clear instructions on how to integrate 3rd party libraries successfully into the project.  I am trying import a 3rd party beacon library that is available for Android.  I am also trying to import other sdks to be built specifically for each side of the development effort.  ie iOS-network-library, and Android-network-library.

I haven't found any specific instructions that work.  Can someone point me to tutorials or explain how I should do this.

Thanks

Comment: there two types of plugins. Method calls and streams

here is an example of a stream plugin https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/sensors

Answer (score 5):

This is what plugin packages are for.

Instructions https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin
Plugin examples https://github.com/flutter/plugins